# First android application interface design - different resolutions/devices/layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, interface

I've picked up a project I started working on a while back - to design my first android application. I have years of experience as an object oriented developer, but very little in graphical interface design. I've been playing around with the on-screen controls and have moved things around a lot, with no real luck or progress. Here are some problems that I'm having:

1. I cant get the button/label layout to show up properly without overlapping with other layouts.
2. I can only get the width/height correct on most controls if I use the "dp" settings rather than specify the dimensions dynamically. This is a problem, as once I switch resolutions, it displays a layout that is borderline unusable.
3. As shown in the top row of the cards, I cant get the containing layout to be the same height as the cards inside them. This makes it too big.
4. Similar to the above problem, I cannot create a buffer area between the cards in the below rows. What I mean is that I want the cards to shrink in size, have a "green space" between the cards, and have the containing layout shrink accordingly. I havent included this change in the mockup below, since it isn't the most important part.

Here is my XML Code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#458B00"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainScreen" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/cardsTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstcard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/secondcard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thirdcard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fourthcard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fifthcard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />
</TableRow>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardsTable"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/suitButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/suitclubs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ca" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/suitdiamonds"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/suitclubs"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/suitclubs"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/da" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/suitdiamonds"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/suitclubs"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/suitdiamonds"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/sa" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/suithearts"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/suitclubs"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/suitdiamonds"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ha" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/numberButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/topRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h2"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h5" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/midRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/seven"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/eight"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h8" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h9" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ten"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/h10" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/bottomRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/jack"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/hj" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/queen"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/hq" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/king"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/hk" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ace"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ha" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/LabelAndDealButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardsTable"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Choose a suit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dealbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/infoLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoLabel"
        android:text="Deal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is I mockup of how I would like the end product to look:
[image: mockup]

Here is what it currently looks like, with that code:

[image: current design]

Any contributions you might have are GREATLY appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I cant get the button/label layout to show up properly without
>   overlapping with other layouts.

The `buttonLayout` `Relativelayout` has a property of `android:layout_below="@+id/cardsTable"` meaning it will take the entire space between the bottom and the top layout. The layout that you try to put between will obviously not be shown. Remove that rule from `buttonLayout`.

> I can only get the width/height correct on most controls if I use the
>   "dp" settings rather than specify the dimensions dynamically. This is
>   a problem, as once I switch resolutions, it displays a layout that is
>   borderline unusable.

Expand on this, it's not clear what you ask.

> As shown in the top row of the cards, I cant get the containing layout
>   to be the same height as the cards inside them. This makes it too big.

You've set a height of `150dp` on the `cardsTable` `TableRow`, you probably want to use `wrap_content`. By the way, `TableRow` is a widget designed to be used in a `TableLayout` and not on its own, replace it with a `LinearLayout`.

> Similar to the above problem, I cannot create a buffer area between
>   the cards in the below rows. What I mean is that I want the cards to
>   shrink in size, have a "green space" between the cards, and have the
>   containing layout shrink accordingly. I havent included this change in
>   the mockup below, since it isn't the most important part.

I'm not sure I understand, but `layout_margin` on the bottom `TableRows` isn't what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I do have to apologize, as I've been constantly changing the XML to try to make it look the way I want. If something looks out of place, it was probably just the remnants of a failed experiment. As for the part I was unclear about, I could set the width/height to 50dp/70dp instead of "wrap_content", for example, but when I look at it from the nexus 10 view versus the nexus 5 the imageviews are too small to be seen well. I'll try your other suggestions and post back. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2961759 Due to the various size in which Android operates it uses a system of layout resources for different configuration. You could use those resource file to use different values based on the device dimensions. A good read would be http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html